# Android Login activity with MySQL database connection

Tags: android

I am doing a tutorial on android "Android Login activity with MySQL database connection"

Please check: http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/search/label/Android

My web service works fine, but when i change my manifest file with --->

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Then my emulator shows nothing and console result is:

```
[2012-07-31 20:51:41 - AndroidLoginExample] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'testdevice'
[2012-07-31 20:51:41 - AndroidLoginExample] Uploading AndroidLoginExample.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-07-31 20:51:42 - AndroidLoginExample] Installing AndroidLoginExample.apk...
[2012-07-31 20:51:46 - AndroidLoginExample] Success!
[2012-07-31 20:51:46 - AndroidLoginExample] \AndroidLoginExample\bin\AndroidLoginExample.apk installed on device
[2012-07-31 20:51:46 - AndroidLoginExample] Done!
```

Comment: Which version of android is your AVD running?

Comment: What do you mean it shows nothing? Like a black screen? '

Comment: BarbiePylon@  It shows normal screen as usual

Comment: DarkXphenomenon@ I am using Android 2.2 and eclipse IDE for Java EE..

Comment: could you post your full manifest?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this part.. application launcher activity might be missing

```
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">     
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
  </action>
```

Comment: Not really ... I have this part...also